# Creating macros in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I wish to create macro in Netbeans to put block comment over function. I have preference of code formatting over file save. So When I close file it saves code automatically and format it.

Issue is when I create function and comment it. It unformatted my whole block of code like this.

```
/**
 *function abc(){
 *var a, b = 50;
 *}
 */
```

I wish to create comment like this. so it keep my coding properly formatted as well.

```
 /*
 |
 | function abc(){
 |     var a, b = 50;
 | }
 |
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own macro by Following this instructions:

1. Edit->Start Macro Recording
2. Edit->Stop Macro Recirding
3. It Will pop-up one Box For Editor Macros->Add Your Choice of Macro Name
4. In code area add Your custom comment code in " your code "; Like,

> Blockquote 
>        "/*
>        |
>        | function abc(){
>        |     var a, b = 50;
>        | }
>        |
>        */"

5. Assign a Short Cut Key to your Custom Macro.

That's It

Answer (score 0):

Though I couldn't find macro for the same. But I found alternative. Use `Ctrl+Shift+R` toggle, for multiple line action at same time & add pipeline sign. But it take extra effort for starting and ending comment.